# 'predict' gives different results than using manually the coefficients from 'summary'

Tags: r, model, floating-accuracy, predict

Let me state my confusion with the help of an example,

```
#making datasets
x1<-iris[,1]
x2<-iris[,2]
x3<-iris[,3]
x4<-iris[,4]
dat<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
dat2<-dat[1:120,]
dat3<-dat[121:150,]

#Using a linear model to fit x4 using x1, x2 and x3 where training set is first 120 obs.
model<-lm(x4[1:120]~x1[1:120]+x2[1:120]+x3[1:120])

#Usig the coefficients' value from summary(model), prediction is done for next 30 obs.
-.17947-.18538*x1[121:150]+.18243*x2[121:150]+.49998*x3[121:150]

#Same prediction is done using the function "predict"
predict(model,dat3)
```

My confusion is: the two outcomes of predicting the last 30 values differ, may be to a little extent, but they do differ. Whys is it so? should not they be exactly same?

Comment: This is perfectly normal the first coefficient is not `-.17947` (it's just the first 4 decimal, and `print(coef(model)[1], digits = 12)` give `-0.179470753385`) try to use coef instead `c(crossprod(coef(model), rbind(1, x1[121:150], x2[121:150], x3[121:150])))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is really small, and I think is just due to the accuracy of the coefficients you are using (e.g. the real value of the intercept is `-0.17947075338464965610...` not simply `-.17947`).

In fact, if you take the coefficients value and apply the formula, the result is equal to predict:

```
intercept <- model$coefficients[1]
x1Coeff <- model$coefficients[2]
x2Coeff <- model$coefficients[3]
x3Coeff <- model$coefficients[4]

intercept + x1Coeff*x1[121:150] + x2Coeff*x2[121:150] + x3Coeff*x3[121:150]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can clean your code a bit. To create your training and test datasets you can use the following code:

```
# create training and test datasets
train.df <- iris[1:120, 1:4] 
test.df <- iris[-(1:120), 1:4]

# fit a linear model to predict Petal.Width using all predictors
fit <- lm(Petal.Width ~ ., data = train.df)
summary(fit)

# predict Petal.Width in test test using the linear model
predictions <- predict(fit, test.df)

# create a function mse() to calculate the Mean Squared Error
mse <- function(predictions, obs) {
  sum((obs - predictions) ^ 2) / length(predictions)
}

# measure the quality of fit
mse(predictions, test.df$Petal.Width)
```

The reason why your predictions differ is because the function `predict()` is using all decimal points whereas on your "manual" calculations you are using only five decimal points. The `summary()` function doesn't display the complete value of your coefficients but approximate the to five decimal points to make the output more readable.